# Java Framework clarity

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

In Java, we have frameworks like Blade,Dropwizard,Grails(groovy-based),GWT,Hibernate,JSF,JHipster,MyBatis,Spark framework,Spring framework,Struts and many more.

We used mainly spring,hibernate,etc. why we have such many frameworks?why all functionalities  are not included in one framework?If someone ask me why did you use this framework,I can't answer.Do We need to know every framework.Someone please provide short documentation which framework to be used when and why?

Comment: What about reading the intro page of each framework before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone is for different tasks, for example Hibernate is used to ease data access, so it can be used only in persistence layer. You are using, whatever makes your work easier and application cleaner, faster and so on...

Some frameworks are built on top of others, for example grails is built on spring-boot and the latter is based on spring. They are making development process even faster and automate many things, for example spring-data-jpa generates methods in runtime, so that you don't fave to write it. Under the hood it uses hibernate.

Some of them are not really frameworks, for example jhipster - it's rather a code generator. It bootstraps an application, both back- and frontend, but actually you're working in spring-boot and angular / react.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question Dhanraj! I'll have a go at answering bearing in mind that I'm just offering my opinion!!

## 1 Why are there so many frameworks?

Commercial profit is certainly one reason. The freedom of developing your own ideas independently of big organisations like Oracle may be another.

## 2 Do we need to know every framework?

John Sonmez in his book 'the Software Developer's Career Guide' talks about only learning what you 'need'. So right now only bother learning the 2 or 3 things you need to complete your home project/the user story you are doing at work. You can think of it like Batman's utility belt! Batman only carries a few of the things he needs around with him, not everything!

John also talks about avoiding 'shiny syndrome', you know when you start working on something and then see a new shinier way of doing it! And then halfway through the job you see another even shinier framework ... and so on! It's a slippery slope and you'll never get anything finished that way! If you've found a framework that does the job, stick with it! So to answer the question as to why you use one framework over another, it's to avoid shiny syndrome!